# How can I create a meta data on `Elasticsearch`?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `Elasticsearch` 6.8. And I'd like to save some `meta` data on my index. The index already existed. I followed this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#add-field-mapping

```
curl "http://localhost:9200/idx_1/_mapping"

{
  "idx_1": {
    "mappings": {
      "1": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to create `_meta` data, I need to create mapping type first.

And I run below code to create a `_meta` mapping type for `version`.

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  "http://localhost:9200/idx_1/_mapping" -d '
 {"_meta": { "version": {"type": "text"}}}'
```

I got below errors:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

It says mapping type is missing. I have specified the `type` for version as `text`. Why does it say `missing type`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I looked at the wrong document version. Based on the doc for Elasticsearch6, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping-meta-field.html, the correct request is:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/idx1/_mapping/_doc" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"_meta": {"version": "1235kljsdlkf"}}'
```